# How to embed an image into another image using C#?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

In my project user will upload an image and the logo of project will be attached(Embeded) to the bottom of the image.

Is it possible to implement?

If yes then how to implement that?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people call this watermarking, I would search around for that.

Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/watermark.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is possible to implement.

Look at the [System.Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) namespace.

You can use the [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) class - it will allow you to load images from files.

Create two bitmaps, one from each image then you should be able to impose the logo image onto the other one.

This is one [fun example](http://weblogs.asp.net/zroiy/archive/2008/10/25/halloween-fun-embedding-ghosts-watermark-in-images-with-c.aspx) of how to do it:

```
Image backImg = Image.FromFile("bg.jpg");
Image mrkImg = Image.FromFile("watermark.png");
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(backImg);
g.DrawImage(mrkImg, backImg.Width/2, 10);
backImg.Save("result.jpg");
```

Comment: getting a bit of quality lose with this