# How can I write a image onto another?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a image that is 500x500, and to this image i want to copy in a symbol that is 32x32, in the upper right corner of the 500x500 image.

I've tried to Render it in, but it does not seem to work:

```
var statusSymbol = new Image()
{
      Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(tempJPEG, UriKind.Relative))
};

WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
wb.Render(statusSymbol , new TranslateTransform() { X = 500-10, Y = 10 });
wb.Invalidate();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to embed an image into another image using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945907/how-to-embed-an-image-into-another-image-using-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual way (with its pros and cons):

```
 public Bitmap AddLogo(Bitmap original_image, Bitmap logo)
    {
        /// Add validation here (not null, logo smaller then original, etc..)
        Bitmap with_logo = new Bitmap(original_image);           

        /// To get the right corner use:
        int x_start_value = (original_image.Width - logo.Width) - 1;
        int x_stop_value = original_image.Width -1;
        /// 

        /// You can add ofset (padding) by starting x and\or y from your value insted of 0

        for (int y = 0; y < logo.Height; y++)            
        {

            /// For left corner
            ///for (int x = 0; x < logo.Width; x++)
            int logo_x = 0;
            for (int x = x_start_value; x < x_stop_value; x++)                
            {
                with_logo.SetPixel(x, y, logo.GetPixel(logo_x, y));
                logo_x++;
            }
        }

        return with_logo;
    }
```